# Onclick и jQuery

Tags: jquery, php, события, javascript

Функция:

```
function pasteHtmlAtCaret(html) {var sel, range;if (window.getSelection) {sel = window.getSelection();
if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {range = sel.getRangeAt(0);range.deleteContents();
var el = document.createElement("div");el.innerHTML = html;var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);}range.insertNode(frag);if (lastNode) {range = range.cloneRange();          range.setStartAfter(lastNode);range.collapse(true);sel.removeAllRanges();sel.addRange(range);}}} else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control"){document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);}}
```

jquery:

```
$('#button').click(function(){$('#area').focus();pasteHtmlAtCaret('inserted');});
```

html:

```
<div id="area" contenteditable="true"></div>

<input type="button" value="Paste" onclick="document.getElementById('area').focus(); pasteHtmlAtCaret('inserted');">

<div onclick="document.getElementById('area').focus(); pasteHtmlAtCaret('inserted');">Вставить</div>
```

Ситуация такова:
 1. Функция pasteHtmlAtCater должна вставлять переданный html в то место, где стоит каретка.
 2. Пункт 1 исполняется только при input onclick. При div onclick и jquery переданный html вставляется в начало.

В чём проблема?

Comment: @Burack Habain, написанный в одну строчку код становится практически нечитаемым. Уменьшение объема скрипта лучше оставить минифаерам.

Comment: вообще говоря, каретка съезжает при потере фокуса, на что вы надеетесь делая `$('#area').focus()` не понятно. если надо помнить где была каретка, то надо ее запоминать при каждом сдвиге

Comment: я порешал

Comment: великолепно